# forwarding domain with htaccess but keep the url structure

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a parked domain www.my-domain.com
I also have a hosted active domain sub.active-domain.com
I want to forward www.my-domain.com to sub.active-domain.com but keeps the url on
structure in the browser from sub.active-domain.com

example:
sub.active-domain.com/content/market.html
will shows on url become
www.my-domain.com/content/market.html

how to do it thru the htaccess file ? or should i do it thru the DNS or CNAME ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be with **.htaccess**. 
But you can not keep the url as long as you redirect it somewhere.
Or other wise use a **iframe**.